# How to change the colour of Font Awesome on UINavigation Bar in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I am new in iOS.And I am facing a problem regarding to change the colour of font awesome label.My code is like this

```
    UILabel *lab =[[UILabel alloc] init];
    lab.text =  [NSString awesomeIcon:FaChild];

    UIImage *listImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
    UIButton *listButton2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    listButton2.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [[listButton2 layer] setBorderWidth:0.5f];
    listButton2.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    listButton2.layer.cornerRadius = calenderbtn.bounds.size.width / 3.4;// this value vary as per your desire
    listButton2.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontAwesome" size:15.0];
    UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                                forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

    NSAttributedString *attributedStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lab.text attributes:attrsDictionary];



    // get the image size and apply it to the button frame
    CGRect listButton2Frame = listButton2.frame;
    listButton2Frame.size = listImage2.size;
    listButton2.frame = listButton2Frame;

    [listButton2 setAttributedTitle:attributedStr forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [listButton2 addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(LogoutClick:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *jobsButton2 =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:listButton2];
```

And it output look like this
[image]
But it in back colour but I write a code for white colour.How to change its colour. Thanks in Advace!

Comment: Did you make sure `FontAwesome` is available in your app? Also, are you trying to set a font on an image? Are you sure?

Comment: @dirtydanee Font Awesome is in my app and I am setting font awesome on UILabel

Comment: You are trying to change the background color of `listButton2 ` ? You want it to be black?

Comment: @dirtydanee I just need to change the colour of label in white colour. Button background colour should be white.

Comment: please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `attrsDictionary` to the second `NSDictionary`, not to the first one.

```
NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font,NSFontAttributeName,color,NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
```

or

```
// using literals

NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}; //
```

You have only set the font property of the label with the first `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thank you very much your code run same just I need.

Comment: no problem. You made this code, but assigned the wrong value to `attrsDictionary `. Next time be more careful! ;)

Comment: Ya sure. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539307/how-to-post-string-with-special-character-and-thai-language-using-xml-parsing-in